# My Android app shows "This app may not be optimized for your device" on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app and released on Google Play Store. When I view the app in the Play Store on Pixel C tablet. There is a message says "This app may not be optimized for your device".

Does anyone know what does the message mean? How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: That can happen because of a lot of reason. Look here :
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Comment: @yuchaozh, what value is set for the minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion?

Comment: @JonBall minSdkVersion 19, targetSdkVersion 24, compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: @yuchaozh, try setting the targetSdkVersion to 25.  Two apps I'm familiar with the app store have targetVersionSdk 23 and targetSdkVersion 25.  The application with targetVersionSdk 23 displays the "This app may not be optimized for your device".  The not optimized message is not displayed for the application with targetSdkVersion 25.

This seems to be a recent change to the Google Play store.  I think these changes were made sometime in November 2017.

Comment: @JonBall, Thanks for the reply. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

In yout build.gradle, try remove targetSdkVersion 26 or change to a lower versi