# Google play says "This app may not be optimized for your device", when I access app page with my tablet

Tags: android, google-play, device, compatibility, tablet

When I access the page of my app in Google play.

I get the following message: "This app may not be optimized for your device"

I am testing with a Samsung Galaxy Tab4 10.1 - matissewifikx Android Version 5.0.2

My app is designed for tablet.

How can I tell google that my app is for tablet and remove this message?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/PqwLNprybOQ;context-place=topicsearchin/play/category$3Aandroid%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false can you check this out.

Comment: Can you share your app device targetting version from build.gradle file

Comment: targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: Duplicate of [My Android app shows “This app may not be optimized for your device” on Google Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445719/my-android-app-shows-this-app-may-not-be-optimized-for-your-device-on-google-p).

Comment: targetSdkVersion could also be called highestSdkVersion.  Anything higher and you may get this message.  From Google: "The minSdkVersion attribute declares the minimum version with which your app is compatible and the targetSdkVersion attribute declares the highest version on which you've optimized your app."  https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Answer (score 9):

This is the same as the old "Designed for phones" message. The [guidelines for getting your app marked as good tablet app quality are here](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality.html).

Comment: in my case is a google play bug, some time after the publication the message disappeared

Answer (score 6):

You need to submit a least one 7-inch tablet and one 10-inch tablet screenshots in your store listing on your Google Play Console.

> For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the
>   Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7-inch and one 10-inch
>   screenshot. If you previously uploaded screenshots, make sure to move
>   them into the right area below.

It's not clearly written that this is related to the message `This app may not be optimized for your device. But I have submitted 7-inch and 10-inch screenshots and as soon as the update were live, the message disappeared.

Comment: In my case I have added 10 inches,7 inches, and mobile phone screenshots, still getting the same message.

Comment: did you find any solution of the same @B.shruti

Answer (score 5):

[Google's quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality.html#support-screens) say "For apps targeting `minSdkVersion` value less than 13, a `<supports-screens>` element must be declared with both `android:largeScreens="true"` and `android:xlargeScreens="true"`." This goes into the `<manifest>` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`, e.g.:

```
<manifest xmlns:android=…..
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
etc
```

Comment: Although, the play store pages of my apps had 7' and 10' size screnshots, the messa ge 'not optimized for tablet' appeared a while ago. And that answer solve my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [optimization tips](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality#google-play-optimization-tips). It will tell you exactly what is missing in your app.

In my particular case the message started showing up when I raised the 
`minSdkVersion` up to 19. The optimization page showed that I was missing [assets designed for tablets](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality#use-tablet-icons)